# The if-statement is repeating itself, as if it were a loop?

Tags: swift, loops, if-statement

```
if let place = placement?[0] {

    if place.postalCode != nil {
        self.currentLocation.text = "Current Location: \(place.postalCode!)"
        self.currentPostalCode = Int(place.postalCode!)

        if (district1ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
           self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 1st"
           representatives.insert(String("Steve Chabot(R)"), at: 0)
        }
        if (district2ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
            self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 2nd"
            representatives.insert(String("Brad Wenstrup(R)"), at: 0)
        }
        if (district3ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
            self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 3rd"
            representatives.insert(String("Joyce Beatty(D)"), at: 0)
        }
        if (district3ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
            self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 4th"
            representatives.insert(String("Jim Jordan(R)"), at: 0)
        }
        if (district5ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
            self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 5th"
            representatives.insert(String("Robert Latta(R)"), at: 0)
        }
        if (district14ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
            self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 14th"
            representatives.insert(String("David Joyce(R)"), at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

So in my code, I have an app that's running this are of code to assign a label to a table, but for some reason, it does this over and over again as if it were a loop but it's an if statement. Please help me out:)

Comment: You need to show more of your code. The problem seems to be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Ignoring that your code is a pain to read—what function contains this code? You keep inserting into the first element: `representatives.insert("...", at: 0)` and your outer-most `if` deals with the first element so these `insert`s may have triggered the function again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't clear if this contributes to the problem since I think that sits elsewhere in your code, this part of the code you posted is incorrect:

```
if (district3ZipCodes.contains(self.currentPostalCode) != false) {
    self.congressionalDistrict.text = "Congressional District: 4th"
    representatives.insert(String("Jim Jordan(R)"), at: 0)
}
```

You are checking district3ZipCodes twice instead of district4ZipCodes